# K&R replace multiple spaces with single space

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLENGTH 1000

void get_input(char ch[], int maxline);
void replace_blanks(char ch[], int z);

int main(void)
{

  char ch[MAXLENGTH];
  int z;

  z = 0;

  printf("Please enter some input. ");
  get_input(ch,MAXLENGTH);
  replace_blanks(ch,MAXLENGTH);

  while(putchar(ch[z]) != EOF)
    {
        ++z;
    }

return 0;

}

void get_input(char ch[], int lim)
{

  int z, i;

  z = 0;

  while((i = getchar()) !=  EOF && z < lim-1 && i != '\n')
      {
          ch[z] = i;
          z++;
      }

  if(i == '\n')
      {
          ch[z] = i;
          z++;
      }

  ch[z] = '\0';

}

void replace_blanks(char ch[], int lim)
{
  char ch_copy[lim];
  int i, arrayindex, copy_counter;

  copy_counter = 0;
  arrayindex = 0;
  i = arrayindex;

  while(ch[arrayindex] != EOF && arrayindex < lim-1){ 
    if(ch[arrayindex] != ' '){
      ch_copy[copy_counter] = ch[arrayindex];
      i = arrayindex;
      arrayindex++;
      copy_counter++;
    }
    else if(ch[arrayindex] == ' ' && ch[i] != ' '){
      ch_copy[copy_counter] = ch[arrayindex];
      i = arrayindex;
      arrayindex++;
      copy_counter++;
    } else {
      i = arrayindex;
      arrayindex++;
    }   
 }

  ch_copy[arrayindex] = '\0';

  for(arrayindex = 0; ch_copy[arrayindex] != EOF && arrayindex < lim-1; arrayindex++){
    printf("%d", arrayindex);
    ch[arrayindex] = ch_copy[arrayindex];
  }

  ch[arrayindex] = '\0';
}
```

Output from this functon from the `printf()` is

```
Please enter some input. hello   hi
0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105106107108109110111112113114115116117118119120121122123124125126127128129130131132133134135136137138139140141142143144145146147148149150151152153154155156157158159160161162163164165166167168169170171172173174175176177178179180181182183184185186187188189190191192193194195196197198199200201202203204205206207208209210211212213214215216217218219220221222223224225226227228229230231232233234235236237238239240241242243244245246247248249250251252253254255256257258259260261262263264265266267268269270271272273274275276277278279280281282283284285286287288289290291292293294295296297298299300301302303304305306307308309310311312313314315316317318319320321322323324325326327328329330331332333334335336337338339340341342343344345346347348349350351352353354355356357358359360361362363364365366367368369370371372373374375376377378379380381382383384385386387388389390391392393394395396397398399400401402403404405406407408409410411412413414415416417418419420421422423424425426427428429430431432433434435436437438439440441442443444445446447448449450451452453454455456457458459460461462463464465466467468469470471472473474475476477478479480481482483484485486487488489490491492493494495496497498499500501502503504505506507508509510511512513514515516517518519520521522523524525526527528529530531532533534535536537538539540541542543544545546547548549550551552553554555556557558559560561562563564565566567568569570571572573574575576577578579580581582583584585586587588589590591592593594595596597598599600601602603604605606607608609610611612613614615616617618619620621622623624625626627628629630631632633634635636637638639640641642643644645646647648649650651652653654655656657658659660661662663664665666667668669670671672673674675676677678679680681682683684685686687688689690691692693694695696697698699700701702703704705706707708709710711712713714715716717718719720721722723724725726727728729730731732733734735736737738739740741742743744745746747748749750751752753754755756757758759760761762763764765766767768769770771772773774775776777778779780781782783784785786787788789790791792793794795796797798799800801802803804805806807808809810811812813814815816817818819820821822823824825826827828829830831832833834835836837838839840841842843844845846847848849850851852853854855856857858859860861862863864865866867868869870871872873874875876877878879880881882883884885886887888889890891892893894895896897898899900901902903904905906907908909910911912913914915916917918919920921922923924925926927928929930931932933934935936937938939940941942943944945946947948949950951952953954955956957958959960961962963964965966967968969970971972973974975976977978979980981982983984985986987988989990991992993994995996997998hello hi
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No no, declare `ch` as `char[]`:

```
char ch[MAXLENGTH];
```

While possible, it's definitely possible to store strings in an `int` array,
you shouldn't do that at all.

I also would write your `get_input` like this:

```
int get_input(char *ch, size_t lim)
{
    if(!fgets(ch, lim, stdin))
        return 0;

    // removing possible \n
    ch[strcspn(ch, "\n")] = 0;
    return 1;
}
```

The logic behind the algorithm seems to be OK, however your `while` and `for`
conditions are a little bit strange and it caused problems when stepping through
the debugger.

```
while(ch[arrayindex] != EOF && arrayindex < lim-1)
```

Don't check for `EOF`, you shouldn't write an `EOF` in
a string, because `EOF` is an `signed int` and doesn't fit in a `char`. If you
read a line with `fgets`, there is never going to be a `EOF` in the string. Also
because you did `while((i = getchar()) !=  EOF && z < lim-1 && i != '\n')` in
the read function, you are not going to have an `EOF` in the string. You should
check for `'\0'` which is the only correct way to terminate a string.

The correct condition would be:

```
while(ch[arrayindex] != '\0' && arrayindex < lim-1)
```

If you are checking for the bounds, then it would be better to have that first
and then check for the end of string.

```
while(arrayindex < lim-1 && ch[arrayindex])
```

Here I omitted the `!= '\0'` because `'\0' == 0`.

After the loop you should do

```
ch_copy[copy_counter] = '\0';
```

Use `copy_counter`, not `arrayindex`, because `arrayindex` is the index for the
original, where multiple blanks are stored. `copy_counter` is the index for the
copy.

But if prior of the `while` loop you did:

```
memset(ch_copy, 0, lim);
```

then the whole buffer would be initalized with 0 and you won't need to worry
about the 0 terminating because the copy will never be larger than the original.

Lastly, the condition in the `for` loop should be corrected with the same logic
as for the `while` loop. Here you don't need to check for the boundaries,
because you know that the copy is never be larger than the original:

```
for(arrayindex = 0; ch_copy[arrayindex]; arrayindex++){
    ch[arrayindex] = ch_copy[arrayindex];
}

ch[arrayindex] = 0;
```

Or you could just use `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(ch, ch_copy);
```

So the function should look like this:

```
void replace_blanks(char ch[], int lim)
{
  char ch_copy[lim];
  int i, arrayindex, copy_counter;

  memset(ch_copy, 0, lim);

  copy_counter = 0;
  arrayindex = 0;
  i = arrayindex;

  while(arrayindex < lim -1  && ch[arrayindex]){
    if(ch[arrayindex] != ' '){
      ch_copy[copy_counter] = ch[arrayindex];
      i = arrayindex;
      arrayindex++;
      copy_counter++;
    }
    else if(ch[arrayindex] == ' ' && ch[i] != ' '){
      ch_copy[copy_counter] = ch[arrayindex];
      i = arrayindex;
      arrayindex++;
      copy_counter++;
    } else {
      i = arrayindex;
      arrayindex++;
    }   
 }

  strcpy(ch, ch_copy);
}
```

Comment: I changed my int * replace_blanks(int ch[], int lim) before I read your post. Is my new version better? It seems to work.

Comment: I mean remove blanks so there is only one blank between words.

Comment: @pumpkinandpeach ah removing multiple blanks between words, I see. I'll have to get a good look at your function then. It will take a couple of minutes then.

Comment: i changed the function and posted the new one at the bottom of my post. I seem to think I get the segmentation error in the for loop at the end of the function for some reason.

Comment: @pumpkinandpeach yes, I noticed, some of my answer if wrong because of that, I'm updating my answer.

Comment: @pumpkinandpeach I'll delete my answer for the time being while I fix my answer.

Comment: alright. Also I am trying to copy the ch_copy array back to the original in the for loop because it wouldn't let me pass the copy back be what I could find said that the copy will be deleted off the stack and than the array would not be referable anymore.

Comment: @pumpkinandpeach it took me longer than I anticipated, I corrected my answer accordingly.